# Shell Script - (Compiling C)

Tags: c, shell, compilation

The second input argument($2) is a path to a c program. 
I need to check if that C program compiles or not.

I believe this is how to compile the C program:

```
   cc $2
```

How can the program tell if the C program file compiled or not?

Comment: Check that `$?` is equal to 0?

Comment: Look at the return code and do what you need to do there.  Check out a shell tutorial.

Comment: Also `cc $2 || echo "compilation failed"`, but then the compiler output would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a POSIX shell (e.g. Bash), you can either write something like this:

```
cc "$2"
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
    # . . . commands to run if it compiled O.K. . . .
else
    # . . . commands to run if it failed to compile . . .
fi
```

or a bit more tersely:

```
if cc "$2" ; then
    # . . . commands to run if it compiled O.K. . . .
else
    # . . . commands to run if it failed to compile . . .
fi
```

In the special case that you simply want to run a certain command if compilation failed, e.g. `exit 1`, you can write something like:

```
cc "$2" || exit 1
```

Comment: will be `=` or `-eq` ? I am bit confused

Comment: @Omkant: Either way. `=` is string-equality, `-eq` is numeric-equality. In this case they both amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In `Bash - shell` You can directly use the following , no need of `if`

```
    cc $2
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1

    # rest of code
```

or you can use,

```
cc $2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
# code for true
else
# code for false
fi
```